# Airflow DAGS Calendar view

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

Is there a view possible in airflow UI that displays what dags are scheduled on a weekly basis? With the current setup, it's hard to understand how many KRI's are scheduled for a day.

Comment: Not in Airflow UI's at the moment unfortunately. There are some external tools such as https://github.com/domenp/aircal which can assist you directly or give you an idea on how to do it.